# Python loop, Index error

Tags: python, function, recursion

I'm new to python, getting an index error on line 6. what's the deal?
trying to create a simple recursion pattern  to solve a problem.

Problem//
For example, suppose the numbers list were [1, 3, 0, 1].  0 redirects to  1, who redirects to  3, who redirects back to 1. There is a loop of two : 1, 3. 
Thus the answer would be 2. Note that even though you started with 0, it is not part of the loop.

some test cases my function must output

## Test cases

Inputs:
    (int list) numbers = [1, 0]
Output:
    (int) 2

Inputs:
    (int list) numbers = [1, 2, 1]
Output:
    (int) 2

```
def answer(numbers,depth=0):
    if depth > 0:
        if depth > numbers:
            return false
        for m in range(0,depth):
            if numbers[m] == numbers[depth]:
                return depth+1;
    return answer(numbers, depth+1)
```

Comment: Can you write it iteratively?

Comment: im sorry i'm not sure,what this is asking, is the for loop not iterating?

Answer (score 0):

```
range(0,depth)
```

returns 0,1,..,depth-1

Also

```
if depth > numbers:
```

does not make sense: comparing integer with list